# SQL pivot need fill 0

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Hi i have big problem with pivot ISNULL i try convert many topics to my code but i failed with this. Its my code with error:

```
  DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @PivotColumnHeaders='';

SELECT @PivotColumnHeaders =@PivotColumnHeaders + '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,Magazyn1) + '],'
FROM
 (      
   Select DISTINCT Pro.SC03002 as Magazyn1
   From SC030700 as Pro
 ) as Topa

SET @PivotColumnHeaders = LEFT(ISNULL(@PivotColumnHeaders,0),LEN(@PivotColumnHeaders)-1)
    DECLARE @Column VARCHAR(MAX);
    set @Column =SUBSTRING(( select distinct ',IsNull(['+SC03003+'],0) as ['+SC03003+']' from SC030700 for xml path('')),2,8000)
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX);
```

-Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 284(set @column)
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
    SET @cmd='
SELECT Pro.SC03001 , '+@Column+'
FROM
(                       
  Select Pro.SC03001 , Pro.SC03002, Pro.SC03003
  From SC030700 as Pro
) AS myProducts
PIVOT (SUM(SC03003) FOR SC03002 IN ('+@PivotColumnHeaders+')) dynamicpivot '
EXECUTE (@cmd)
```

Comment: What are the values in these 2 variables when you execute it or what is the contents of cmd?

Comment: How i can check this? We dont have instaled debuger. I know how to debug only in VS.

Comment: Meyby exists simple hint to fill nulls? :)

Comment: your error is because you're trying to do something like     `'Hey' + 10`.. you can't  concat a varchar with an int that way.. you either need to cast the `10 ` as a varchar or if you are using SQL 2012 you can use `CONCAT('Hey', 10)`

Comment: you are also summing `SC03003` so why are you using that field in your @Columns.. shouldnt you be using SC03002 instead

Comment: SC03003 is quantity / SC03001 is product ID / SC03003 is WarehauseID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast those numeric columns to varchar explicitly so you can concatenate them to your string:

```
set @Column =SUBSTRING(( select distinct ',IsNull(['+CAST(SC03003 AS varchar(31))+'],0) as [SC03003]' from SC030700 for xml path('')),2,8000)
```

Comment: oops, yes, I fixed it.

Comment: What do you mean you can't convert?

Comment: Goooood :) but i have more errors but is my fault :)

Answer (score 0):

try casting column `SC03003` to a varchar since you're adding it to a string value.

```
set @Column =SUBSTRING(( select distinct ',IsNull(['+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, SC03003)+'],0) as [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SC03003) +']' from SC030700 for xml path('')),2,8000)
```